# GIT Script file not showing correct output

Tags: git, batch-file

My requirement is to open a GIT Bash Window and execute few commands.
For this I have created a Batch.sh file and written the script like:

```
#!/bin/bash
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin\sh.exe" --login
cd '/D/Work/R8/D3000/Repo/R8'
```

When I execute Batch.sh file, Git Bash command prompt is opened and output is

```
IC008988@AAEINGN533211D /d
```

I expect output should be
 `IC008988@AAEINGN533211D /D/Work/R8/D3000/Repo/R8`

Can anybody tell me what is problem in my script?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is the start directory.

You can create a shortcut to your script, or by pin your script to taskbar or somewhere, then you can set the start up directory in the properties dialog of the shortcut.

See http://windows.tips.net/T010869_Changing_Shortcut_Properties.html